# Linked List too large to manage

Tags: list, list-view, query

I have a list linked to a Microsoft Access Table it exceeds the 10,000 line limit. How can i create views if it exceeds the limit?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable **list throttling at the list level**.
You must have *Farm Administrator privileges*.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://url/to/web/with/list
$list = $web.Lists[“BIG_LIST_NAME”]
$list.EnableThrottling = $false
```

Some links about the topic: 
[Techniques for managing large lists](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SharePoint-lists-V-Techniques-for-managing-large-lists-13456600-ff66-46ec-a2d2-91736d4a166e)
[Manage lists and libraries with many items](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Manage-lists-and-libraries-with-many-items-11ecc804-2284-4978-8273-4842471fafb7)
[List Throttling](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2009/10/27/working-with-large-lists-in-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling.aspx)
[Disable list throttling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mimorr/archive/2012/08/28/disable-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling-at-the-list-level.aspx)